# Python MySQLdb slow in updating values

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update a database with values from a csv file, the following is my code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
import csv

con = None
command = ''
new_name_list = []
old_name_list = []
duplicates = []
update_list = []
file = 'csv_file.csv'
listReader = csv.reader(open(file, 'r'))
for row in listReader:
    new_name_list.append(row)

try:

    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword', 'mydb')
    con.autocommit(True)

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT fil_name FROM file WHERE fil_name like 'boy%' and fil_job_id=1")    

    numrows = int(cur.rowcount)

    for i in range(numrows):
        file_name = cur.fetchone()
    old_name_list.append(file_name[0])

    d = dict(new_name_list)

    for n in old_name_list:
        try:
            print n + " has been updated to " +  d[n]
            command = "UPDATE file SET fil_name='" + d[n] + "' WHERE fil_name='" + n + "'"
            cur.execute(command)
        except KeyError:
            duplicates.append(n)

except mdb.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:    

    if con:    
        con.close()
```

It takes about 2-3 seconds for each print to appear, which leads me to think that the update execution is being made slowly. I have a lot of values to update and this should not be the speed that it should be executing (given that I was able to get a quick printout of all the values of `d[n]` )

Is there anyway to speed up the updating?

**EDIT:** The database is using InnoDB engine

Comment: Are you sure its running 2-3 seconds per loop and not just flushing the sys.stdout slowly? Have you tried adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description,each print cost 2~3 seconds,so i think the problem maybe of this:

1. do you have your fil_name column of table file indexed?
2. you make auto_commit be true,each update is a transaction commited.

If the case is 1,just create index on that column,do not make table scan on updating.

If the case is 2,@dave gives a good answer.

Comment: How do I check if it is indexed and if no, how do I do that?

Comment: 1,show index from table_name:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

Comment: 2,create index index_name on table_name(index_col_name):http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-index.html

Comment: I can't use index because my database is InnoDB

Comment: Opps, my bad, saw special indexes instead of index. Working on it now, will comment back later

Comment: Another question, how should I update my table after indexing the column?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the update speed is much faster now. Didn't know that indexing will speed up the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using `executemany`:

```
data = [(n, d[n]) for n in old_name_list]
cur.executemany("UPDATE file SET fil_name='%s'  WHERE fil_name='%s'", data)
```

Additionally, you may want to consider indexing fil_name (assuming fil_name is read-mostly)

Comment: Should those `'?'` be `'%s'` ?

Comment: Upvoted! That was probably an enormous performance suggestion. It actually covered two issues. Doing a batch query, AND using parameters instead of doing string concat. You might also add the suggestion that the OP ensure the "fil_name" field is indexed

Comment: @androidnoob, perhaps try committing?

Comment: @dave I have `con.autocommit(True)`

Comment: @dave is the `executemany()` method use iterate in the backend? because it's still very slow to me, 300,000 rows update takes over 10 minutes. I don't use the autocommit, the where field has been indexed. Do you think concatenate the sql query to a long string like `update ...; update ...;`, then use `execute(sql)` will improve the performance?